# How to implement long/complex query with spring-data-jpa 2.1

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I need some advice with implementing spring JPA query. My query is complex, because of the input length.
As input I've:

- 15 condition - check equality if not null;
- 2 condition - check between if not null
- Additionally, the output must be pageable.

I know that this can be solved by using standard PagingAndSortingRepository like:

```
Page<A> findAllByParam1AndParam2AndParam3Between...(@Nullable String param1, @Nullable String param2, @Nullable Integer param3,...)
```

but looking on how long my input is this solution looks unclear and I don't think that method with so many parameters is a good solution.
I was also thinking about `findAll` by Example, but this is supporting equality, not the between condition.

***Any other options?***
The only way to go is by building a custom query with **CriteriaBuilder**?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Derived queries, i.e. those deriving the actual query from the method name, are the wrong tool for such long or complex queries because the resulting name becomes unusable.

Alternatives that you should consider are

- using a fixed query provided in a `@Query` annotation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query
- using a named query where you provide the query on the entity: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.named-queries
- using a specification where you dynamically assemble the where clause: https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/

Comment: Could you please fix the links

Answer (score 1):

You have below options to do that.
1) use hql , for that it is mandatory to have all the tables mapped as jpa entities
2) is to use native queries, the downside here is that it affects the portability of the application, but if u r sure that ur application is not going to migrate on any other database then u can use this
3) is to use criteriabuilder

Edit-> Found our that @Query can be used for both SQL and JPQL to execute .

Please follow below link for more information

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query

Usage of Query in some spring developer certification books also.

Hope that helps